# URL deemed invalid in XML

Tags: xml, validation, url, encoding

When I try to validate this XML, I get an error:

```
<url>http://example.org/?a=1&b=2</url>
```

The validator says: "Reference to entity "b" must end with the ';' delimiter." in reference to the second equal sign (=) in the string.

Why does this happen? Should the URL be encoded somehow?

Answer (score 6):

`&` is not allowed in XML, since it starts an entity sequence (usually a named reference to a character, like `&eacute;` for `é`). Entity sequences start with a `&` and end with a `;`, and between them is enclosed the name of the entity.

To insert `&`, write this entity sequence: `&amp;`.

There are several more characters that need to be written as entities: a double quote `"` (`&quot;`) when it is inside a XML attribute, and angle brackets `<`, `>` (`&lt;`, `&gt;`), since they have special meanings in XML.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a protected character in XML.

You can replace it with the entity `&amp;`

```
<url>http://example.org/?a=1&amp;b=2</url>
```